# MVC 3 ASP.NET Roles-Authorize Attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, active-directory, authorization, user-roles

I am getting user roles from Active Directory and I am binding the same roles to ASP.NET Membership Roles.

I want to control the display for the various Views in Controller by using

```
[Authorize(roles="Admin")]
```

But Which ever role I specify, The View just doesn't display. If I take out the `[Authorize(roles="Admin")]` it works.

Does Authorize uses ASP.NET Membership roles? if so, Why I am getting this error?

Am I missing anything? Any Ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

IIRC if you use AD roles it works with groups and you need to specify the domain:

```
[Authorize(Roles = @"MYDOMAIN\SomeDomainGroup")]
```

Now if the user accessing the site belongs on the given AD group he will be granted access.

Comment: @Hari Gillala, my point is that the `Role` property is used with AD groups. So you should specify the AD group that you want to grant access to.

Comment: I tried with [Authorize(Roles = @"Domainname\groupname")], Nothing gets displayed. If I take out the attribute [Authorize] then it works but there is no point for me to do that. I don't know why its behaving in this format.

Comment: So you must limit you application to only ever working on the specified domain, or you must write your own Authorize attribute that checks the name of the group only.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using the VS built in server and you are getting a blank page - the built in development server will display a blank page instead of prompting for credentials.

Buried way down in a note on [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg703322%28v=vs.98%29.aspx)

```
Note:
If you are using the Visual Studio Development server, you are not prompted for credentials and you see only a blank page.
```